# Why does using "Self" as a parameter type raise a lifetime error?

Tags: rust, type-inference, lifetime

I'm currently following along with https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html but I'm implementing everything in Rust. Here's a excerpt from my vector implementation:

```rust
type Scalar = f64;

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
pub struct Vector {
    x: Scalar,
    y: Scalar,
    z: Scalar,
}

impl Vector {
    fn new(x: Scalar, y: Scalar, z: Scalar) -> Self {
        Self { x, y, z }
    }

    fn x(&self) -> Scalar {
        self.x
    }

    fn y(&self) -> Scalar {
        self.y
    }

    fn z(&self) -> Scalar {
        self.z
    }
}

impl std::ops::Mul<&Vector> for &Vector {
    type Output = Scalar;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        self.x() * rhs.x() + self.y() * rhs.y() + self.z() * rhs.z()
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following message:

```
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/point.rs:33:5
   |
33 |     fn mul(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(&point::Vector, &point::Vector) -> _`
              found fn pointer `fn(&point::Vector, &point::Vector) -> _`
note: the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 30:20...
  --> src/point.rs:30:20
   |
30 | impl std::ops::Mul<&Vector> for &Vector {
   |                    ^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 30:20
  --> src/point.rs:30:20
   |
30 | impl std::ops::Mul<&Vector> for &Vector {
   |                    ^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `raytracing`.
```

However, if I change the `Self` parameter on the `mul` function to `&Vector`, it compiles just fine:

```rust
[...]
fn mul(self, rhs: &Vector) -> Self::Output {
[...]
```

Is this just a case where the lifetime inference fails? If so, why is it failing, since the compiler seems to have inferred everything correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of rule of [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html), the error message tell it:

> note: the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 30:20...

The line:

```rust
impl std::ops::Mul<&Vector> for &Vector {
```

is interpreted as:

```rust
impl<'a, 'b> std::ops::Mul<&'a Vector> for &'b Vector // Self is &'b Vector
```

and so lifetime mismatch because:

```rust
fn mul(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
```

is

```rust
fn mul(self, rhs: &'b Vector) -> Self::Output {
```

`&'a Vector` != `&'b Vector` so it's can't compile. Cause `rhs` should be `&'a Vector`.

When you use `Self`:

```rust
impl std::ops::Mul<Self> for &Vector {
```

become:

```rust
impl<'a> std::ops::Mul<&'a Vector> for &'a Vector {
```

so in `fn mul(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {` `rhs` will have the correct lifetime `<'a>`

If a lifetime problem occurs try to be explicit to check if compiler get it wrong.

The final code should not contain any `Self` keyword to allow different lifetime:

```rust
impl std::ops::Mul<&Vector> for &Vector {
    type Output = Scalar;

    fn mul(self, rhs: &Vector) -> Self::Output {
        self.x() * rhs.x() + self.y() * rhs.y() + self.z() * rhs.z()
    }
}
```

explicit:

```rust
impl<'a, 'b> std::ops::Mul<&'a Vector> for &'b Vector {
    type Output = Scalar;

    fn mul(self, rhs: &'a Vector) -> Self::Output {
        self.x() * rhs.x() + self.y() * rhs.y() + self.z() * rhs.z()
    }
}
```